# Trying to read data out of MSysObjects with ODbc in C#, but getting no permission error

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010

As described in the title:
I am trying to read out data from MSysObjects in a Access 2010 database, but I get an exception telling me I am not allowed to read from that table.

I can read out of the other non-MSys Tables.

```
SQL Query I am using: SELECT * FROM MSysObjects WHERE Type=1 AND Flags=0
```

Connection String:

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\mydatabase.accdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;
```

This is the standard Connection Sting as seen on http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

How can I get access to read from MSysObjects ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your db is ACCDB format, that means the db engine sees *Admin* as the user who runs all your queries.  And *Admin* does not have read (`SELECT`) permission for `MSysObjects`.

Execute a DDL `GRANT` statement to give *Admin* that permission.

```
GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;
```

I'm not certain that statement can be executed from an ODBC connection.  If it fails, open the db in an Access application session and run it there.

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"
```

Note that statement *must* be executed from ADO.  `CurrentProject.Connection` is an ADO object, so its `Execute` method can run the statement successfully.  If you try to use some DAO-based method, such as `CurrentDb.Execute` or run the statement as a query in the query designer, it will fail with error 3129, *"Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."*

Alternatively, it should work from c# if you run it from an OleDb connection to the Access db.

Comment: I tried to execute your first query within Acces itself and via my own programm, and both hasn't worked.

Comment: Access expected a Select, Edit, Delete command, not a grant.  I found a workaround so I don't need to change the permissions as I don't need to read out the MSysObjects anymore. I'll stop working on this problem, but further discussions are welcome. Thanks hans.

Comment: Use `CurrentProject.Connection` to execute the statement in Access.