# Query to check if a table in access database exists

Tags: sql, ruby, ms-access-2007

I want to use a query to check if there exists a table in my access database, if not then I can create that table. I'm using Ruby to call functions to execute SQL query, such as Insert, Select, Update, Create etc.

I looked up some solutions such as MSysObjects, but it doesn't work for the Access 2007.

So anyone who is familiar with Access database can help me with this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the version of access you are using?  When people find this question later, "the latest version of Access"  will be different than it is now.

Comment: If you *must* use a query to check whether the table exists, you will have to alter the `MSysObjects` table permissions to give yourself read permission.  There are other methods (but not a query) to check whether a table exists.  Can you use something other than a query?

Comment: I'm actually using Ruby to call a method Execute which execute SQL query statement, so I guess that's the only way I can do this

Comment: If you know how to handle errors from Ruby, consider attempting to create the table and trapping the error when the table already exists.

Comment: @HansUp, Thank you for the tip. I'm new to Stackoverflow, learned a lot. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you want to use the query approach, give yourself read permission on `MSysObjects`.  Try the DDL statement I suggested in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18124087/77335).

Comment: @Hansup, thank you for the advice, I was trapped into finding queries to solve this issue but forgot I could catch the exception. It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved, I was trapped into finding SQL queries to solve this issue, but I forgot I could catch the exception when there was no such a table exists and then do some actions. Thanks for @HansUp's advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Exists = IsObject(CurrentDb.TableDefs(tablename))
```

Comment: When `tablename` is a name which does not exist, that will throw error #3265, *"Item not found in this collection."*

Comment: I'm trying to run this one, but it gives me error "Invalid SQL statement; expected SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE...."